# I am using jupyter i am not able to find the video file

Tags: python, opencv, jupyter-notebook

I have 120 images at folder in Jupyter.

I want to create a video from this images, and I am using **OpenCV** tool but i am not able to find the video.

```
import cv2
image = ''
image_arr = []
for i in range(1,121):
    if i < 10:
        x =  '000' + str(i) 
        image = x + '.jpg' 
        out_scores, out_boxes, out_classes,output_image = predict(sess, image)
        image_arr.append(output_image)

    if 100 > i >= 10: 
        x =  '00' + str(i) 
        image = x + '.jpg' 
        out_scores, out_boxes, out_classes,output_image = predict(sess, image)
        image_arr.append(output_image)
    if  i >= 100:
        x =  '0' + str(i) 
        image = x + '.jpg' 
        out_scores, out_boxes, out_classes,output_image = predict(sess, image)
        image_arr.append(output_image)
#To Create video        
video = cv2.VideoWriter('test.avi',cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v'), 20, (608,608))
for i in range(len(image_arr)):
    video.write(image_arr[i])
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
video.release()
```

Can someone please tell me what's wrong?

Comment: try `import os   print(os.getcwd())` to show the current working directory likely where your 'test.avi' file is being saved

Answer (score 0):

You can't *store files in Jupyter. It's a python virtualization manager, not a file system (unless you are talking about JupyterHub). You placed the file in some directory on your PC. Find where that is. In a new cell in your notebook, type the following:

```
!pwd
```

This will print the current directory of your notebook. At this point, you can move the images to the folder of your jupyter instance or you can run jupyter in a different directory.

Comment: is the file is placed at pc ? or not?

Comment: @MohamedFarag What folder is the video in? And what is the output of the code I wrote above?